# A three digit number $\overline{ABC}$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $\overline{AB} - \overline{2C}$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't know how I would begin proving an if and only if problem like this. Specifically, how would you prove if one side then the other with this type of structure? Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your digits are $A,B,C$, your number is:

$C+10B+100A$. $AB-2C$ is the number: $10A+B -2C$. Suppose $AB-2C$ is divisible by $7$. Then $100A+10B-20C$ is divisible by $7$. But $110A+10B+C-(100A+10B-20C)=21C$ which is divisible by $7$.

Similarly the other part follows.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$ABC-21 \times C =10\times(AB-2C)$$

As $21 \times C$ is divisible by $7$ it follows that $ABC$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $10\times(AB-2C)$ is divisible by $7$. Now use that $7$ and $10$ relatively prime...

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

Hint: $ABC=100*A+10*B+C$.If ABC is divisible by 7 it means that $ABC=0$ mod 7, so

$100*A+10*B+C=0$ mod 7 is 0 too. Try to show when your equality holds by this way.